# How long can laptops stay safely off?

Tags: laptop, lifespan

Are there any concerns regarding the battery or other components when a laptop stays off for a long period of time? (in ranges of weeks, months or years).

More specifically, I am interested in:

1. Being able to use a laptop safely after leaving it off for a long period of time without having to later fix or replace any components.
2. Potential health hazards from keeping a laptop off at home and then trying to use it again.

Comment: Related: [Storing a laptop for a month](http://superuser.com/questions/314951/storing-a-laptop-for-a-month)

Comment: Forever. It's turning it back ON that's the problem.

Comment: This is a specific question with a few specific answers. I don't see why it's been closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this has been asked before but can't tell where.

**These are what you need to keep in mind:**

- The battery works using chemical reactions, these reactions cannot be
  stopped but they can be slowed.
- A laptop with the battery left in will continue using that battery
  very slowly.
- A battery left completely dead inside a laptop that is still trying
  to draw power will kill the battery completely.

**So here are the answers:**

If you are storing the system for just weeks, simply take the battery out and leave both in a cool dry place away from direct light.

If you are storing the laptop for a few months, do the same, but take better care where you store the laptop and battery. Placing them in a case, or completely dry bags to prevent dust buildup.

If you are storing the laptop for years, the battery will probably be dead when you come back. But you'll also want to take the laptop apart and remove the small battery keeping the BIOS going. This will drain and expire and may corrode inside the laptop.

Comment: Probably be dead? It will be dead.

Answer (score 3):

I'll recommend following steps:

1. Pack your laptop in airtight plastic bag so that dust will not go inside.
2. Before you pack make sure you drain your battery to 50% and then pack the laptop with 50% charge left.
3. Backup your important data.
4. Remove the battery and pack your laptop.

This should enough to go!

Here is a link from HP who recommends similar steps for long term storage:
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01297640&tmp_track_link=ot_recdoc/c00817650/en_us/c01297640/loc:4&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&product=4121143

Comment: +1 for nice tips, can you explain why 2 is necessary and has to be 50%?

Comment: Leaving the battery in the laptop is not a good idea if you are storing the system for more than a week. A battery drained this way may not be able to be charged again at all. Also, what is the importance of the 50% charge?

Comment: Li-ion batteries are simply best stored with a 50-80% charge. I don't know the exact physics, but it's something along the lines of a fully charged Li-ion battery is under a chemical stress, which is fine for short periods of time, but for long periods it causes the battery to deteriorate.

Answer (score 1):

If there would be damage to your system, it would be due to environmental climate changes like temperature, humidity, earthquakes and similar causes. Laptops can stay off for a very long time, it is however suggested that you disconnect the wire and remove the battery to prevent power leakage.

*Have been on vacation for 3 weeks. Confirmed to work as fine as before...*